# Excel euro negative numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the custom cell with the below formatting

```
_-[$€-x-euro2] * #,##0.00_-;-[$€-x-euro2] * #,##0.00_-;_-[$€-x-euro2] * "-"??_-;_-@_-
```

How to show negative number inside brackets ?

Answer (score 1):

Do display the negative values between brackets you can use the following codes:

```
_-[$€-x-euro2] * #,##0.00_-;([$€-x-euro2] * #,##0.00);_-[$€-x-euro2] * "-"??_-;_-@_-
```

Will result in:

[image]

```
_-[$€-x-euro2] * #,##0.00_-;[Red]([$€-x-euro2] * #,##0.00);_-[$€-x-euro2] * "-"??_-;_-@_-
```

Will result in:

[image]

Alternatively,

```
_-[$€-x-euro2] * #,##0.00_-;[Red][$€-x-euro2] * (#,##0.00);_-[$€-x-euro2] * "-"??_-;_-@_-
```

Will result in:

[image]